# Loop is breaking before Modifying player position in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, maze

I have a small maze game in python and the end is defined by 2 or G and when you get to the end you win but I want to actually show the player that they went onto the G and it Turns into a D for done and then the loop breaks but the loop breaks before thus happens and I tried making it work with a var called at_goal but its still no working, can someone help?

Code:

```py
import random
import time
maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

player_x = 1
player_y = 1

at_goal = False

done = False
while done == False:
    print("\033[H\033[2J", end="")
    for y, row in enumerate(maze):
        for x, element in enumerate(row):
            if x == player_x and y == player_y:
                if at_goal:
                    print("D", end=" ")
                else:
                    print("P", end=" ")
            elif element == 1:
                print("#", end=" ")
            elif element == 2:
                print("G", end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print()
    move = input("Enter a move (up, down, left, right): ")
    if move == "up":
        player_y -= 1 
    elif move == "down":
        player_y += 1
    elif move == "left":
        player_x -= 1
    elif move == "right":
        player_x += 1
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
    
    if maze[player_y][player_x] == 2:
        at_goal = True
    elif maze[player_y][player_x] == 1:
        print("You have hit a wall and lost the game. Try again.")
        player_x = 1
        player_y = 1
        at_goal = False
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if at_goal:
        print("You have reached the goal and won the game!")
        done = True
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is that you're using **at_goal** to check if the player has reached or not but you're not using **at_goal* to update the maze itself. Try this solution.

```
import random
import time

maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

player_x = 1
player_y = 1

done = False
while done == False:
    print("\033[H\033[2J", end="")
    for y, row in enumerate(maze):
        for x, element in enumerate(row):
            if x == player_x and y == player_y:
                print("P", end=" ")
            elif element == 1:
                print("#", end=" ")
            elif element == 2:
                print("G", end=" ")
            elif element == 3:
                print("D", end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print()
    move = input("Enter a move (up, down, left, right): ")
    if move == "up":
        player_y -= 1 
    elif move == "down":
        player_y += 1
    elif move == "left":
        player_x -= 1
    elif move == "right":
        player_x += 1
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
    
    if maze[player_y][player_x] == 2:
        maze[player_y][player_x] = 3  # update the maze to reflect that the player has reached the goal
        print("You have reached the goal and won the game!")
        done = True
    elif maze[player_y][player_x] == 1:
        print("You have hit a wall and lost the game. Try again.")
        player_x = 1
        player_y = 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: This code does not work

Answer (score -1):

the solution for this problem is very simple.
Your while loop stops before the last print that you need. To solve that you can move the code to show the table to a function, and then call the function at the end of the game. The final logic looks like this:

```
import random
import time
maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

player_x = 1
player_y = 1

at_goal = False

def print_table():
    print("\033[H\033[2J", end="")
    for y, row in enumerate(maze):
        for x, element in enumerate(row):
            if x == player_x and y == player_y:
                if at_goal:
                    print("D", end=" ")
                else:
                    print("P", end=" ")
            elif element == 1:
                print("#", end=" ")
            elif element == 2:
                print("G", end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print()

done = False
while done == False:
    
    print_table()
    move = input("Enter a move (up, down, left, right): ")
    if move == "up":
        player_y -= 1 
    elif move == "down":
        player_y += 1
    elif move == "left":
        player_x -= 1
    elif move == "right":
        player_x += 1
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
    
    if maze[player_y][player_x] == 2:
        at_goal = True
    elif maze[player_y][player_x] == 1:
        print("You have hit a wall and lost the game. Try again.")
        player_x = 1
        player_y = 1
        at_goal = False
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if at_goal:
        print_table()
        print("You have reached the goal and won the game!")
        done = True
```

Comment: when i lost or make an invalid move the print table functions generates an extra part uptop, 

# # # # #
# # # # #
# P     #
#       #
#       #
#       #
#       #
# G     #
#       #
#       #
# # # # #


it starts generating useless stuff

Comment: Could you give more info? The only change that my code did was to show the table on the win part.

Comment: I tested the game here again. The winning and losing possibilities. I could not replicate your problem. I'm sorry.